# How to Implement beforeunload event Listener in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, events

I have this rough code in Javascript, I want to implement this code in my react application but I am not sure how to implement them in react.

**Overview of my requirement** --

> I want to clear a particular token from local storage unless the user **closes all the tabs or
> exits the browser**, so the next time user tries to open the application
> he needs to log in again, So I took a reference of this code, but I don't have any idea where to use this in React.

```
window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
    localStorage.removeItem('logged-in');
}

let loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('logged-in');
let sessionLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('logged-in');
if(!loggedIn) {
    if(sessionLoggedIn) {
        localStorage.setItem('logged-in', JSON.parse(sessionLoggedIn));
        //go to authenticated space
        window.location.href = '/authenticated';
    } else {
        //go to login
        window.location.href = '/login';
    }
} else {
    //go to authenticated space
    window.location.href = '/authenticated';
}

window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'logout' && event.newValue) { 
        sessionStorage.removeItem('logged-in');
        localStorage.removeItem('logout');
        window.location.href = '/login';
    }
});
```

Can someone guide me on where to implement this code in react application do we need to use any hooks for watching for beforeunload event?

Any help would be much appreciable, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information given I would say that you should put the following code into your `index.js` or similar.

```
    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', yourFunction)
     
      return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', yourFunction)
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Firstly thanks bud, Will this run when the application gets loaded? In my case, I needed it when we close all tabs or at the time of closing a browser, so will it run when that situation occurs? sorry I am not good at this, that's why I want to clear my thoughts

Comment: @Madhan1021 np, it depends on where you put it. If you put it in your index.js file it should run when the app is loaded. It's hard to say with 100% certainty without seeing your project structure.

The event works as follows: "The beforeunload event is fired when the window, the document and its resources are about to be unloaded".

But the event itself is not the most reliable. So you should really try to find another solution. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleUnloadEvent);

  return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleUnloadEvent);
}, [handleUnloadEvent]);
```

I've added [handleUnloadEvent] to the 2nd attribute of useEffect to prevent adding and removing the event listener on every state change.

Comment: No need to add a dependency. With the empty dependency array the useEffect will only run and add the EventListener when component mounts. And remove the EventListener when component demounts. And next time component mounts it will add the EventListener once again. Changes to state will not add or remove anything unless components demounts or you have the state in the dependency array.

Comment: Are you sure that in the question mentioned must be added event listener in the component mount phase ? What will be happen if component will be re rendered ? will your useEffect work again with empty dependencies ? @ohmyzZz

Comment: Re-Render and Mounting are different things. Mounting is when a component is rendered for the first time and the DOM is built. Re-render is when an already mounted component is called with new data/instructions. UseEffect with empty dependency array only runs on mount.

Comment: Okay good answer and details you were wrote about mounting and re render , why I have wrote handleUnloadEvent as a dependency , because of prevent adding and removing the event listener on every state change. Are you sure that need this event listeners on the mount/demount phase ? I am not sure. @ohmyzZz

Comment: If I understand your question correct, yes you need to add the EventListener when mounting the component, and yes you should always remove EventListener when demounting a component.